# $\mathcal{L}$ is very ample, $\mathcal{U}$ is generated by global sections $\Rightarrow$ $\mathcal{L} \otimes \mathcal{U}$ is very ample

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathcal{L},\mathcal{U}$ be invertible sheaves over a
noetherian scheme $X$, where $X$ is of finite type over a noetherian
ring $A$. If $\mathcal{L}$ is very ample, and $\mathcal{U}$ is
generated by global sections, then $\mathcal{L} \otimes \mathcal{U}$
is very ample.

Since $\mathcal{L}$ is very ample, there exists $n$, s.t. $i:
X\mapsto \mathbb{P}^n$ is an immersion with $\mathcal{L}=
i^*\mathcal{O}(1)$, and since $\mathcal{U}$ is generated by global
sections, one can construct $j:X \to \mathbb{P}^m$ with
$j^*\mathcal{O}(1) = \mathcal{U}$. From this I can construct the
following morphism:

$$
h: X \xrightarrow{\Delta} X\times X \xrightarrow{i\times j}
\mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m \xrightarrow{ \operatorname{segre \
embedding}} \mathbb{P}^N $$

I can prove $\mathcal{L}\otimes \mathcal{U } \cong
h^*\mathcal{O}(1)$, and the segre embedding is a closed immersion.
But I don't know whether the map $(i\times j) \circ \Delta$ is an
immersion, which is suspicious to be such, especially for the
$\Delta$.

Comment: This is Hartshorne's Exercise II.7.5 (d), and his Exercise II.7.4 (a) shows that $\Delta$ is a closed immersion.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But is $i \times j$ also an immersion? I can prove $X \times \mathbb{P}^m \to \mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m$ is an immersion, but not for the whole morphism.

Comment: $i\times j=\left(i\times \mathrm{id}\right)\circ \left(\mathrm{id}\times j\right)$, and the composition of two immersions is an immersion (this follows from the fact that a closed subscheme of an open subscheme is always an open subscheme of a closed subscheme if everything is Noetherian; this is Exercise 9.3.C in Vakil's notes http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/ ).

Comment: Note that Vakil comments that calling these things "immersion" here is a bad idea.

Comment: Now I am wondering: Isn't your proof symmetric in $\mathcal L$ and $\mathcal U$? Aren't you proving that the tensor product of two very ample sheaves is very ample?

Comment: Ah, I see! $j$ needs not be an immersion.

Comment: Oh, Liu has the proof (more or less): Let $\pi$ be the projection $\mathbb P^m\to \mathrm{Spec}A$. Then, $\left(\mathrm{id}\times \pi\right)\circ \left(i\times j\right)\circ \Delta = i$ is an immersion, while $\mathrm{id}\times \pi$ is separated (by Hartshorne's Corollary II.4.6 (c)), so that Hartshorne's Exercise II.4.8 (applied to $\mathcal P = \text{"being an immersion"}$) yields that $\left(i\times j\right)\circ \Delta$ is an immersion. Let's hope this isn't wrong again...

Comment: Yeah, that works! By the way, can you point out where is the Liu's result as you quoted above. Is that from Liu Qing 's book Algebraic geometry and arithemetic geometry?

Comment: Yeah, it's from that book. Chapter 5, Exercise 1.28.

Answer (score 4):

From the comments, to clear this from the unanswered queue:

> Let $\pi:\Bbb P^m\to \operatorname{Spec} A$ be the projection. Then, $(\text{id}\times\pi)\circ (i\times j) \circ \Delta = i$ is an immersion, while $\text{id}\times \pi$ is separated (by Hartshorne's Corollary II.4.6(c)), so that Hartshorne's Exercise II.4.8 (applied to $\mathcal{P} = \text{"being an immersion"}$) yields that $(i\times j)\circ \Delta$ is an immersion.

This argument is sourced to Liu's Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves, Chapter 5, Excercise 1.28. This comment was originally written by darij grinberg (2011-11-29), and at the time of this posting was comment-upvoted at +7 as well as confirmed by the original asker in a subsequent comment.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that if $i: X \to Y$ is an immersion, and $j:X \to Z$ is *any* morphism (all over $S$), then $(i, j): X \to Y \times_S Z$ is an immersion. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535049/if-p-ix-rightarrow-y-ii-1-2-are-immersions-is-x-rightarrow-y-1-times-y/3170483#3170483) for a proof.