# Divisor is the difference of effective divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

**Q**:

- How to show that on the smooth projective variety $X$, any divisor $D$ can be represented by the difference of two effective divisors, i.e. 
  $D=D_1-D_2$.
- If $X$ is just any complex manifold, does above also hold?

Comment: Isn't this true by definition of a divisor? A divisor is just a formal $\mathbf{Z}$-linear combination of codimension one subvarieties of a variety $X$. So you just express $D$ as the part of the linear combination with positive coefficients, minus the part with negative coefficients. Depending on what you mean by a divisor on a complex manifold, the same argument works.

Comment: A more subtle question is whether you can choose $D_1,D_2$ to be *smooth* divisors. See [this other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1732888/116766) for how you can ensure this version, at least on a smooth projective variety over an infinite field (note it is written for surfaces, so just replace "curve" with "divisor" to make the proof work in arbitrary dimension).